# Why is the ketone not attacked by the Grignard reagent/cuprate in this case but a double bond is?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

[image: question]

According to the book the answer is (a)
Here I assume transmetallation occurs and then the nucleophilic carbon of methyl attacks the ring but what I don’t understand is why the ketone remains unaffected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book is correct. This is a classic example of a 1,4-addition (also called a conjugate addition) of an alkyl nucleophile to an α,β-unsaturated ketone. Normally, a Grignard reagent such as MeMgBr would indeed attack the carbonyl carbon in what is referred to as a 1,2-addition (also called a direct addition). However, treatment of the Grignard with a cuprous halide (CuI, in this case) changes the reaction entirely.

This can be explained well by hard-soft acid-base theory, or [HSAB theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory).
Methylmagnesium bromide is a relatively "hard" nucleophile and therefore preferentially reacts with the hard electrophile (the carbonyl carbon) in a 1,2-addition. After treatment with a proton source, product D is afforded.

But, in the presence of CuI, MeMgBr reacts to form an organocuprate with the stoichiometry of Me<sub>2</sub>CuMgBr. The details of the cuprate formation — and of the true structure of the cuprate itself — are complicated and still somewhat unclear. Nevertheless, this resulting organocuprate species is a much softer nucleophile than is the Grignard. It therefore preferentially attacks the softer carbon electrophilic site. A lone pair on the oxygen of the resulting enolate anion then reforms the carbonyl double-bond as the π-electrons of the enolate C=C double-bond attack <sup>n</sup>PrI to form a new C-C single bond, affording product A.

[image: Mechanisms of both 1,2- and 1,4 addition.]